# Find and replace in multiple files

Tags: php

OK, whats the best solution in php to search through a bunch of files contents for a certain string and replace it with something else.

Exactly like how notepad++ does it but obviously i dont need the interface to that.

Answer (score 25):

```
foreach (glob("path/to/files/*.txt") as $filename)
{
    $file = file_get_contents($filename);
    file_put_contents($filename, preg_replace("/regexhere/","replacement",$file));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So I recently ran into an issue in which our web host converted from PHP 5.2 to 5.3 and in the process it broke our installation of Magento. I did some individual tweaks that were suggested, but found that there were still some broken areas. I realized that most of the problems were related to an issue with the "toString" function present in Magento and the now deprecated PHP split function. Seeing this, I decided that I would try to create some code that would find and replace all the various instances of the broken functions. I managed to succeed in creating the function, but unfortunately the shot-gun approach didn't work. I still had errors afterwards. That said, I feel like the code has a lot of potential and I wanted to post what I came up with.

**Please use this with caution, though. I'd recommended zipping a copy of your files so that you can restore from a backup if you have any issues.**

**Also, you don't necessarily want to use this as is. I'm providing the code as an example. You'll probably want to change what is replaced.**

The way the code works is that it can find and replace whatever is in the folder it is put in and in the sub folders. I have it tweaked so that it will only look for files with the extension PHP, but you could change that as needed. As it searches, it will list what files it changes. To use this code save it as "ChangePHPText.php" and upload that file to wherever you need the changes to happen. You can then run it by loading the page associated with that name. For example, mywebsite.com\ChangePHPText.php.

```
    <?php
    ## Function toString to invoke and split to explode

    function FixPHPText( $dir = "./" ){
       $d = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir );
       foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $d, 1 ) as $path ){  
          if( is_file( $path ) && substr($path, -3)=='php' && substr($path, -17) != 'ChangePHPText.php'){ 
              $orig_file = file_get_contents($path);
              $new_file = str_replace("toString(", "invoke(",$orig_file);
              $new_file = str_replace(" split(", " preg_split(",$new_file);
              $new_file = str_replace("(split(", "(preg_split(",$new_file);
              if($orig_file != $new_file){
                file_put_contents($path, $new_file);
                echo "$path updated<br/>";
              }
          }
      }
    }

    echo "----------------------- PHP Text Fix START -------------------------<br/>";
    $start = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
    echo "<br/>*************** Updating PHP Files ***************<br/>";
    echo "Changing all PHP containing toString to invoke and split to explode<br/>";
    FixPHPText( "." );

    $end = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
    echo "<br/>------------------- PHP Text Fix COMPLETED in:". sprintf("%.4f", ($end-$start))." seconds ------------------<br/>";
    ?>
```